# Codeigniter Route Confusion

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, uri

I am building a URL shortener web site.

Here is my `config/routes.php` file:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "main";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['(\w{2})/(.*)']        = '$2';
$route['(\w{2})']             = $route['default_controller'];

$route['join']                = 'main/join';
$route['activate/(:any)']     = "main/activate/$1";
$route['login']               = 'main/login';
$route['logout']              = 'main/logout';
$route['main/login']          = 'main/login';
$route['main/join']           = 'main/join';
$route['url/short']           = 'url/short';
$route['user']                = 'user/index';
$route['user/index']          = 'user/index';
$route['user/index/(:num)']   = 'user/index/$1';
$route['profile']             = 'user/profile'; 
$route['user/delete/(:any)']  = "user/delete/$1";

$route['(:any)']              = "url/go/$1";
```

Well, as you see, I implemented language as mentioned on CI Wiki [here](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/URI-Language-Identifier).

But now the last line of route is not functioning normally.

```
$route['(:any)']              = "url/go/$1";
```

For example, `myshortner.com/as34v` should match with above route and redirect to full URL, but instead it redirects to `0.0.0.1` ! How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have url as a controller with go as function expecting a numeric parameter? otherwise it will go to your default controller which is main and look for what is there in the index function.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "instead it redirects me to `0.0.0.1`"? I mean, the only way you'd know what it redirected to was when a certain controller's function was called, and `0.0.0.1` doesn't really have a meaning in that context

Comment: The third parameter should be a valid `method` name of `class` and you have passed `$1` as a method name which doesn't exist.

Comment: i have a url controller and go method that takes $1 as shourt url key and fetchs long url with it. finally redirects to long url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you shoulf have a URL controller with a "go" function that takes a parameter held in $1. Make sure that exists.

Comment: Please tell me if any conflict between first rwo routes and the last route. maybe this is the problem.

Comment: I don't see anything in the routes that would cause issue. Since you are debugging put an echo in your controller function and make sure when you use that url that the controller is actually being hit. If your debug message prints then there is a logic issue in your code and not the routes. If the message does not print, comment out everything other than the last line of your routes. Let me know the results.

Comment: Actually I think I see the issue with the route. Can you provide the test url you are using? Thanks.

Comment: It seems trying to reach an unexisted parameter.

Comment: Right. With the last case if you used something like www.mysite.com/something/page then /something/page would get sent to your go controller method with two parameters "something" AND "page" instead of something/page. You would have to account for this in your go function with php's func_get_args or handle it with one additional route with a $2.